# URL parameters not shown in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link with parameters like this:

```
graphs_dashboards_path(survey_id: @survey.id, level: 1)
```

So I expect the view to have a link like this: `dashboards/graphs?survey_id=1&level=1`. But it only has a link like this: `dashboards/graphs`.
What am I missing, where are the URL parameters? I have other links with URL parameters working fine, so I can't figure out why they are missing here?

The link:

```
link_to "Graphs", graphs_dashboards_path(survey_id: @survey.id, level: 1)
```

The routes:

```
  resources :dashboards, only: [:index] do
    collection do
      get :graphs
      get :kpis
      post :scope
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sounds like something to do with the route to which you're passing these arguments.  Can you include the code relevant to your `graphs_dashboards` route? (including any other resources in which it might be nested)

Comment: For completeness, please include the `link_to` portion as well, just so we have all our bases covered.

Comment: Added both the link and the routes

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't reproduce your same setup works as intended. What version of Rails are you running and could you copy/paste the html output? Double check that html matches the `link_to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had a link like this:

```
%li= link_to I18n.t "dashboard.index_title", graphs_dashboards_path(survey_id: @survey.id, level: 1)
```

Because the I18n translation didn't have parenthesis, the link_to got confused. Just adding parenthesis solved the issue:

```
%li= link_to I18n.t("dashboard.index_title"), graphs_dashboards_path(survey_id: @survey.id, level: 1)
```

I removed the I18n translation from the question to make it not too complicated, I am sorry!